# Show that if $f$ is differentiable then...

Tags: calculus

> Show that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then one may expand $f$ around $a$ as $$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a) +(x-a)E(x)$$
>   where $E(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$

If $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then we have $$f'(a)= \lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

We can multiply both sides by $(x-a)$ and we get 
$$\begin{align}
(x-a)f'(a) & =  \lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} (x-a) \\
           & = \lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\lim_{x\to a} (x-a)
\end{align}$$

I can't seem to go any further than this, is this a correct way to tackle this problem? A little hint in the right direction would be appreciated and preferred. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be to *define* $E(x)$ (for $x \neq a$) as
$$ E(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} - f'(a),$$
(so that, if you rearrange this, you'll get the equation you wrote down).

It only remains to show that $\lim_{x \to a} E(x) = 0$. For this step, just remind yourself of the definition of the derivative $f'(a)$, and the proof should hopefully be obvious!

Comment: Thanks very much, very simple and concise answer.